# Converting String Cell to Double type

Tags: excel, vba

I am working with VBA and firstly look at my code :

```
Sub ali()
a = [C13]
Dim b As Double
b = CDbl(a)
MsgBox b
End Sub
```

my cell which is C13 is = 0.5 typed manually in cell and I want to msgbox the B variable which should be the double number of the cell but it appears error of type mismatch and i don't know what to do!!!

Comment: In which of those lines do you get the error? What is your decimal separator?

Comment: my decimal operator is (.) like 3.4 and in line 13 i get eror

Comment: OK and what is the output of `Debug.Print Application.DecimalSeparator` If you run that in the immediate window? And What is the output of `Debug.Print [C13]`?

Comment: my debug.print is = 0.5 and the out put of Debug.Print Application.DecimalSeparator is = /  I mean slash!!

Comment: That is your problem then. Why the heck did you set your decimal separator to slash? Change it to `.` and it works: [Change the character used to separate thousands or decimals](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/change-the-character-used-to-separate-thousands-or-decimals-c093b545-71cb-4903-b205-aebb9837bd1e)

Comment: i def tried that too, but working with combobox it doesn't work

Comment: you are doing something wrong then. If the decimal separator is set properly that code works. Change `[C13]` into a proper code that references the workbook and worksheet properly `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("C13")` to ensure it does not pick the wrong sheet.

Answer (score 0):

You will get an error if cell `C13` is not numeric, so check that first.

```
Sub ali()
  a = [C13]
  If IsNumeric(a) Then
    Dim b As Double
    b = CDbl(a)
    MsgBox b
  Else
    MsgBox "not numeric"
  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: yes it was not numeric but how i can make that cell numeric?

Comment: If it's something like "tree" then you cannot make that numeric. If it's something like "123" then that is already numeric and can be converted to the decimal `123` as the code above demonstrates. So, what is the value when it errors?

Comment: it is a decimal number and that is = 0.5 but it deoen't seem to know this as a number or float